# overloading with runtime type in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, types, runtime, overloading

Consider following code:

```
public class A
{
    public A(){}
}

public class B:A
{
    public B(){}
}

public class C
{
    public C(){}
    
    public void fun(A a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("that was A");
    }
    
    public void fun(B b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("that was B");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A(), b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        c.fun(a);
        c.fun(b);
    }
}
```

In the current form, it says `"that was A"` twice. How to fix class `C`, so that `fun(B b)` is invoked when `b`'s runtime type is `B`, but compilation type is `A`? Currently it works properly only when I declare `b` as `B` during compilation.

@Edit: without checking types with `if`s etc.

Comment: You're declaring `b` as type `A`, so the static type information available causes it to call `fun(A)`. Avoid declaring two variables in the same statement like that.

Comment: So I think you might want to look into late binding (Edit: Dynamic Dispatch thanks other commenter). Essentially in C# (and other languages) overload resolution is done at compile time. A pattern called  the Visitor Pattern or Double Dispatch in OOP  languages is usually whats put forward to handle this

Comment: The correct solution is to use virtual methods on A to have the two types provide different implementations of the same method, rather than having multiple overloads for different types.

Comment: useful blog https://chodounsky.com/2014/01/29/dynamic-dispatch-in-c-number/

Comment: `c.fun((dynamic)b);` is what you are trying to write... Indeed as @madreflection hinted at this is doing mad reflection... but to some extent C# does support it... Sometimes it may be useful for visitor pattern (where you can't push code to be virtual methods on the elements)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke `fun` via a virtual method.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void fun(C c) 
    {
        c.fun(this);
    }
}

public class B:A
{
    public override void fun(C c) 
    {
        c.fun(this);
    }
}

public class C
{
    public void fun(A a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("that was A");
    }

    public void fun(B b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("that was B");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        A a = new A(), b = new B();
        C c = new C();
        a.fun(c);
        b.fun(c);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
that was A
that was B
```

[See example on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V3Zmft)